# Convert a function to local function (lambda)

Tags: c++, lambda

I want to make `FindFirstKey1` function into a lambda function called `FindFirstKey2`:

Here's what I tried:

```
#include <vector>

struct Point
{
    int x;
    int y;
};

bool FindFirstKey1(std::vector<Point> &m, Point &FirstKeyFound, int currentKeyIndex, int SearchKey)
{
    if (currentKeyIndex < m.size())
    {
        auto key1 = m[currentKeyIndex];

        if (key1.x <= SearchKey)
        {
            FirstKeyFound = key1;
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}


int main()
{
    std::vector <Point> m;
    Point FirstKeyFound;
    int currentKeyIndex;
    int SearchKey;

    bool FindFirstKey2 = [&m, &FirstKeyFound, currentKeyIndex, SearchKey]()
    {
        if (currentKeyIndex < m.size())
        {
            auto key1 = m[currentKeyIndex];

            if (key1.x <= SearchKey)
            {
                FirstKeyFound = key1;
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    };


    FindFirstKey1(m, FirstKeyFound, currentKeyIndex, SearchKey);
    FindFirstKey2(m, FirstKeyFound, currentKeyIndex, SearchKey);
}
```

I am still getting some errors I don't understand:

> Error C2440   'initializing': cannot convert from
> 'main::<lambda_55baf115e13173580997f8ba93ea8513>' to 'bool'

What do I need to make it work i.e. call the lambda function just the way I call regular function?

Comment: You seem to be trying to assign the lambda to a bool. Error correctly points out, that the types of those are incompatible, to be assigned that way. Did you intend to invoke said lambda, and assign the result, that lambda returns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems with your code.

Problem 1:

```
bool FindFirstKey2 = [&m, &FirstKeyFound, currentKeyIndex, SearchKey]()
```

The type of a closure, or a lambda, is an anonymous class. It is not a `bool`, therefore this should be:

```
auto FindFirstKey2 = [&m, &FirstKeyFound, currentKeyIndex, SearchKey]()
```

Problem 2:

```
FindFirstKey2(m, FirstKeyFound, currentKeyIndex, SearchKey);
```

`FindFirstKey2` is a closure that takes no parameters. See above. You declared it as a closure, or a lambda, that captures four objects by reference and takes no parameters, but here you are calling it and passing to it four parameters.

You will need to reconcile this difference, one way or another. Either you need to change the closure to take four parameters, or don't pass any parameters to the closure when you're calling it.

Comment: I ran into one another problem. I moved `m` to be a class member and this lambda function is now under a class's public member function. Do I need to capture this `m` by reference in same way? I tried it says `::m` is not a variable.

Comment: One question per stackoverflow.com question, please. Feel free to post a new question, making sure that the new question, as always, meets all requirements of a [mre].

Answer (score 1):

If you want to replicate the functionality of `FindFirstKey1`, this is the syntax:

```
auto FindFirstKey2 = [](std::vector<Point> &m, Point &FirstKeyFound, int currentKeyIndex, int SearchKey) {
   // Here your code
};
```